# Chrome SSL Issue

Tags: google-chrome, ssl

I am using `windown 8.1` and `Google Chrome 63.0.3239.132 (Official Build) (64-bit)`

I have added some hosts in my `HOSTS` file that point to a `Virtual Machine` IP address (Where web server is listening).

Every thing is working fine in other browsers but Google Chrome redirects to `https`. As local site is running on `http`, I receive **`ERR_SSL_PROTOCOL_ERROR`**

How can I stop Google Chrome for redirecting some selected address to `https`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Chrome forces certain domain names to be redirected to https, maybe the domain name you are using is in this list of domain names (it would be very coincidental, but still ...).

See [https://ma.ttias.be/chrome-force-dev-domains-https-via-preloaded-hsts/]  and [https://www.chromium.org/hsts]

Comment: Yes, I was using .app with hostname and coincidentally, chrome forces .app address to https. Thanks Jos